# Regex for find and replace strings in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace words using regular expressions. But it's not working.

I'm trying to replace only the words that have one **dot (.)**

**My column:**

```
           Names   
   House is cold     
         a.blala     
        myname.s  
  Tables are old      
          L.NAME  
         E. Name
```

**I tried:**

```
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace(r'([a-z]|[a-z]+)|([A-Z]|[A-Z]+)\..?([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)|([A-Z][a-z]+)', '<person>')
```

But this regular expression replaces all the text in this dataframe.

**Good output**

```
           Names   
   House is cold     
        <person>     
        <person>  
  Tables are old      
        <person>  
        <person>
```

Comment: `'words that have one'`? This statement is unclear. you mean strings with only one word? contain string one?

Comment: Do you mean one `.` (dot)?

Comment: maybe he meant words that have one '.' - dot.     so if it has a full stop like 'a.blala', then it replaces with '<person>'. that is my interpretation.

Comment: Use `^[^.]*\.[^.]*$`, see https://regex101.com/r/4uFmll/1

Comment: Normally, in regular expressions, a dot stands for `any character`. If you want to refer to the dot as a reguar character, you'll need an escape character (like the backslash, just proposed by Wictor).

Comment: what happens if it has space after a dot/full stop. Is it still valid?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Duplicate with javascript????????? My question is about python!!!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But I do not know any other programming languages! Do you think I should look for answers in javascript if my goal is python and I do not know javascript? How would I know it works everywhere????

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for single `.` use:

```
import numpy as np
df['Names'] = np.where(df['Names'].str.count('\.')==1, '<person>', df['Names'])
df
#            Names
#0   House is cold
#1        <person>
#2        <person>
#3  Tables are old
#4        <person>
#5        <person>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
df['names'] = np.where(df['names'].str.contains('\.'), '<person>',df['names'])
```